# INSERT ... RETURNING whole row instead of specifying each column

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

When inserting a new entity I want to return the inserted row. I think I could use

```
INSERT INTO person (username, password) 
VALUES ('user', 'pw')
RETURNING username, password, created_at, updated_at
```

but as you know some tables have many columns. Is there a way I return the full row with all the columns without specifying them? I have many insert and update statements and would like to avoid doing everything by hand.

Comment: I am not aware that MySQL or MariaDB support `output`, so I'm confused by your question.  Plus, your title uses `RETURNING` -- which is only supported in the most recent MariaDB release.

Comment: I'm sorry, wrong sql dialect ... I fixed the sample :)

Comment: Have you tried `RETURNING *`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to the [documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/insertreturning/). Here is a quote:

> INSERT ... RETURNING was added in MariaDB 10.5.0, and returns a resultset of the inserted rows.

Your syntax is incorrect. It should be:

```sql
INSERT INTO person (username, password)
VALUES ('user', 'pw')
RETURNING username, password
```

If you want all the columns then add them to the column list and provide default values in the VALUES clause.